# How to modify Pandas's Read_html user-agent?

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, urllib2

I'm trying to scrape English football stats from various html tables via the [Transfetmarkt](http://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/en/premier-league/gegentorminuten/wettbewerb_GB1.html) website using the pandas.read_html() function.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
url = r'http://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/en/premier-league/gegentorminuten/wettbewerb_GB1.html'
df = pd.read_html(url)
```

However this code generates a **"ValueError: Invalid URL"** error.

I then attempted to parse the same website using the urllib2.urlopen() function. This time i got a "HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found". After the usual trial and error fault finding, it turns that the urllib2 header presents a python like agent to the webserver, which i presumed it doesn't recognize.

Now if I modify urllib2's agent and read its contents using beautifulsoup, i'm able to read the table without a problem.

Example:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
url = r'http://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/en/premier-league/gegentorminuten/wettbewerb_GB1.html'
response = opener.open(url)
html = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
table = soup.find("table")
```

How do I modify pandas's urllib2 header to allow python to scrape this website?

Thanks

Comment: You might want to put up an issue over on GitHub. I'd be happy to take a look (I wrote `read_html`)

Comment: done - https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4927

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Currently you cannot. Relevant piece of code:

```
if _is_url(io): # io is the url
    try:
        with urlopen(io) as url:
            raw_text = url.read()
    except urllib2.URLError:
        raise ValueError('Invalid URL: "{0}"'.format(io))
```

As you see, it just passes the `url` to `urlopen` and reads the data. You can file an issue requesting this feature, but I assume you don't have time to wait for it to be solved so I would suggest using BeautifulSoup to parse the html data and then load it into a DataFrame.

```
import urllib2

url = 'http://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/en/premier-league/gegentorminuten/wettbewerb_GB1.html'
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
response = opener.open(url)
tables = pd.read_html(response.read(), attrs={"class":"tabelle_grafik"})[0]
```

Or if you can use `requests`:

```
tables = pd.read_html(requests.get(url,
                                   headers={'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}).text,
                      attrs={"class":"tabelle_grafik"})[0]
```

Comment: @PhillipCloud I put the comment there to clarify what the `io` is :)

Comment: ah okay...carry on then :)

Comment: @Viktor I've sorta got it working, however the pd.read_html function returns a list and not a dataframe. 
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import pandas as pd 
url = r'http://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/en/premier-league/gegentorminuten/wettbewerb_GB1.html'
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
response = opener.open(url)
html = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
tables = pd.read_html(str(soup), attrs={"class":"tabelle_grafik"})

Comment: `read_html` returns a `list` of `DataFrame`s because many pages have multiple tables.

Comment: Also @user2158866 I've put up a PR that uses your URL as a test case. Check the issue on GitHub.

Comment: @user2158866 as Phillip said `read_html` returns a list of DataFrames. In this case you are probably searching for the first one in that list. Also you don't need the `bs4` at all. I updated the example.

Comment: We should *really* think about using `requests` over at `pandas`. That's so much better than passing around an `OpenerDirector` instance. I think we have an issue about using `requests` somewhere...

Answer (score 2):

Starting from pandas 2.1.0 *[a custom header can be sent alongside HTTP(s) requests by passing a dictionary of header key value mappings to the `storage_options` keyword argument](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/io.html#reading-writing-remote-files)*.

```
import pandas as pd

headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"}
df = pd.read_html(
    "http://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/en/premier-league/gegentorminuten/wettbewerb_GB1.html",
    storage_options=headers
)
```

See also

- [ENH: support `storage_options` in `pandas.read_html`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/49944).

Comment: This is the answer I came here looking for.... worked perfectly.